# Why do variable drawable and getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) refer to different objects respectively?

Tags: java, android

The code is very simple.
I want to change the image of a FrameLayout when clicking button.

The following statement is not working: 
`if(framgLay.getForeground() == getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)`

So, I solved the problem with following code..
But, I don't know the reason why `drawable` and `getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)` refer to different objects respectively.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

FrameLayout fl1;
Drawable drawable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fl1 = findViewById(R.id.fl1);
    drawable = getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    fl1.setForeground(drawable);

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    if (fl1.getForeground() == drawable) {
        fl1.setForeground(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_circle_black_24dp));
    } else {
        fl1.setForeground(drawable);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because when you call `getDrawable(...)` it will create new instance of that drawable which contains the same image, while the `==` will compare the references for those two instances. The solution is the following:

```
if (fl1.getForeground().pixelsEqualTo(drawable)) {
    // here equals
}
```